# C++ lambda value can't capture

Tags: c++, lambda

Here is my code,I want to test closure in c++ like javascript. Why the compiler yield this message?     "testLambda.cpp: In lambda function:
    testLambda.cpp:8:11: error: ‘a’ is not captured"

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <functional>
    std::function<bool(int)> returnLambda(int a){
        auto b  = 1;
        auto c  = 2;

        return [&](int x)
        {   return x*(b++)+c+a == 0;};
    }
    auto f = returnLambda(21);
    int main(){
        auto c = f(1);
        auto b = f(1);

        std::cout<<c<<b<<std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `[]` is where you put the capture variables.

Comment: If you have a problem which is solved by an answer, but then run into a new problem, don't change your question. Ask a new question, in a different post.

Comment: -1 question editted to make no sense.  Please revert.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to specify your captures in the square brackets, that's why lambdas require square brackets in the first place.  You can capture them by reference:

```
[&a,&b,&c] (int x) ...
```

or by value:

```
[a,b,c] (int x) ...
```

or mix it up:

```
[a,&b,c] (int x) ...
```

Or you can just capture everything that you use:

```
[&] (int x) ... // by reference
[=] (int x) ... // by value
```

If you choose to capture a variable by value, but need to modify it, then you need to make it mutable:

```
[=] (int x) mutable ...
```

Comment: Thanks ,i change my code a little,but it says Segmentation fault.The problem is the 'a' in lambda funciton

Comment: @Ryan_Liu - If you capture by reference than you are responsible to ensure the object is still alive when the lambda is called

Comment: Deleted my original comment as you clarified it in your answer. It has to be mutable when capturing by value and changing the value.

Answer (score 2):

Benjamin Lindley provided an answer about declaration of lambdas in C++.

But technically speaking you cannot reproduce JavaScript closures using C++ lambdas.

In JS outer variables that used by local function are protected by GC mechanism.

But in C++, if you capture variables by reference, you can easily get into situation when referenced variables are destroyed and you'll get segmentation fault / access violation.

This, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
std::function<bool(int)> returnLambda(int a){
    auto b  = 1;
    auto c  = 2;

    return [&](int x)
    {   return x*(b++)+c == 0;};
}
auto f = returnLambda(21);
int main(){
    auto c = f(1);
    auto b = f(1);

    std::cout<<c<<b<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

will crash badly as after return from the returnLambda() its variables a,b and c are destroyed (their stack location is used by something else) when function f() is called.

Comment: If you want that behavior, then make your local variables shared pointers, and capture them by value in the lambda.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley Yes, there are technics to *simulate* closures in C++ but it is a simulation indeed. Closure in JS is function reference + reference to chain of call frames (objects in heap). So basically all technics shall simulate that call frame chain in one form or another.